# Best way to compute an overall Stack Exchange reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Suppose I wanted to condense my reputations across the Stack Exchange network into a single number that I could brag about.  The following methods come to mind, but have their flaws:

- **Average reputation:** This would penalize me for joining new SE sites, as the default rep of 100 for signing up would pull my average down.
- **Maximum reputation:** Would be great if I was a standout contributor to one particular site, but if I focus my efforts on a handful of sites then this might not be so accurate.
- **Sum of all reputations:** I could game the system by joining all the sites I possibly could.

**How could I compute an overall Stack Exchange reputation that accurately reflected my contributions all networks?**  This should be an absolute number, not a rank of some kind.

Comment: Use flair to calculate rep earned in sites with 200 plus rep

Comment: Sum of reputation from all sites, but excluding the association bonus?

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer adding up the 200+ reps as a grand total, like how it is done in Area51. It is a nice way to calculate the total effective rep across all SE networks.

The same is used in calculation of the flair but adjusted to the nearest four characters.

So, if you want to calculate your total rep, instead of just the 200+ sites, then you need to calculate from 101+.

However, on one or more sites, you might have been participating from a rep score of 1 (i.e. before getting to 200 on any site), those sites should be calculated from 1. A list of these can be found from the reputation plots on your SE profiles.

Comment: Flair actually just does it to the nearest 4 characters (including decimal points and the k symbol). So for instance a rep of 4556 combined would show up as 4.6k

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a modification of your option three, to really see what reputation you have gained only from contributions. This is an idea I'd had upon reading the question, but was originally posted in a much shorter form by [chirlu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274410/best-way-to-compute-an-overall-stack-exchange-reputation/274517#comment891757_274410) in the comments.

You could do this with a small equation: `M - (100 * s)` where `M` is your total reputation across all sites you have an account on, and s is the number of sites you have an account on. The 100 is the value of the association bonus.

Using your network profile, I've calculated your current total reputation at 5761 across 38 sites. `5751 - (100 * 38) = 1961`

If you also wish to exclude the 1 rep every account starts with before you reach the association bonus, then the equation would be `M - (101 * s)` which in your case would be `5761 - (101 * 38)` or 1923.

For users who have yet to hit the association bonus on any network site, this equation would not work. For those users, I see two ways to alter the equation to achieve the same result: `M - s` or `M` depending on if they wished to exclude the 1 starter rep per site. This is accurate enough, as none of their network accounts have yet had 100 bonus rep added to them, and therefore all the rep each account has must have been earned through contributions (or is the 1 starter rep on an account to which they have not yet contributed or had only negative contributions.) and does not need removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the third option, sum of reputation, and to prevent gaming it, take only sites where you have at least one upvoted post, either a question or answer. This way just joining a site won't boost the stat, you'll have to actually contribute to the site. (and not only via edits)

So, going with this, your "Enhanced Overall Stack Exchange Reputation" at the moment is:

521+478+280+231+222+183+166+160+143+143+128+124+123+121+121+111+106 = 3361.

(Excluding Area51 which is not Q&A site, and its reputation system is so old and broken, that most users there have wrong reputation anyway)